# Sharing methods among some of the derived classes in UML

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

I am struggling with modeling a specific scenario. Let's say we have a super class and three subclasses.

The subclasses share a list of methods from the super class. However, there is one method which is needed to be shared by two out of three classes. So, I thought of two scenarios:

1. Adding the method in the two subclasses. If I do that though, I will have code duplication since the implementation of the method is same.
2. Keep the method in the super class to avoid code redundancy based on scenario one above. However, wouldn't that allow the third class to inherit the method? Which defeats the purpose.

So, any ideas on how to model such a scenario ?

Comment: Don't think in terms of what methods your classes have. Think in terms of what is there task/purpose. Then reconsider if inheritance is a good solution.

Comment: As @JensSchauder indicated, there is no **useful** way to answer that question without knowing the real classes and operations. Sure we can think of many possible scenario's, but there's no way of choosing the right one without knowledge of the classes and operations we are talking about. Classes are more then a bunch of features that can be inherited. They should form a consistent, logical grouping of attributes, relations and behavior that belong to a class with a clear definition and purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of your two scenarios is particularly good. The need to inherit a certain method in two out of three classes suggests that you are probably missing an abstract class in the middle, from which two classes inherit:

```
public class Top {
    public void method1() {}
    public void method2() {}
}
public abstract class AbstractTwoAndThree extends Top {
    public void method3() {}
}
public class Derived1 extends Top {
}
public class Derived2 extends AbstractTwoAndThree {
}
public class Derived3 extends AbstractTwoAndThree {
}
```

This way, all three `Derived` classes inherit `method1` and `method2`, while `method3` is inherited only by `Derived2` and `Derived3`.

**Note:** The reason I made the class in the middle `abstract` is to stress that it is intended to be inherited, and must not be used by itself. It is not necessary to add any abstract methods to it.

> **Comment:** What if we need to create a sharing graph that is not a tree?

In situations like that you need multiple inheritance for implementation, which is not available in Java. However, multiple inheritance of interfaces is available, which will let you declare the methods that you need only in the classes that must have them. Now you can offload the implementation into a package-private class, or put a default implementation into the interface, depending on the nature of the method:

```
public class Top {
    public void method1() {}
    public void method2() {}
}
public interface TwoAndThree {
    void method3() {}
}
public class Derived1 extends Top {
}
class TwoAndThreeHelper { // The class is not public
    public static void method3impl(TwoAndThree inst) {
        ... // Implement the method
    }
}
public class Derived2 extends Top implements TwoAndThree {
    public void method3() {
        // Call the shared implementation to avoid duplicating code
        TwoAndThreeHelper.method3impl(this);
    }
}
public class Derived3 extends Top implements TwoAndThree {
    public void method3() {
        // Call the shared implementation to avoid duplicating code
        TwoAndThreeHelper.method3impl(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very good design. What if I add another class called class4 and suppose that method3 is needed by claases 1, 2, and 3 but not 4. And a new method called method4 is needed by two and three only. How would we model it? We cannot create a two abstract classes (one for method3 and one for method4) because we can't inherit two classes.

Answer (score 0):

With pure UML, you are allowed to inherit from multiple classes at once.
That is, you may model a second superclass containing that method, from which only the two subclasses may inherit (in addition to the common superclass).

Reference: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html#multiple-inheritance

This becomes problematic when implementing your diagram in languages that disallow this, such as Java (where you have to choose either of your two solutions. But for the first solution, you could also add an interface, so that at least the method is declared in a central place). But until then, on a conceptual level, you are fine :)

Comment: That's a very good point. I did not know that UML allows multiple inheritance. But a again as you mentioned, it can be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'd come up with:
[image]

Just create a sub-class from `Main` and add method you need for your both classes.